# How to find the salt part from password hash of each user in openldap? ( sha 512 hash)

Tags: openldap

I have user password in plain text format. What i want to do is, i want to find the hash of the plain text password using sha512 and compare the result with password retrieved from openldap. But problem here is i could not find the Salt used by the openldap for the sha512 hashing.

(i.e)
   In linux from /etc/shadow , we can find the salt,  $6$salt$hash

similarly how to find the salt from password hash stored in openldap

System Environment:-
        Linux,c,c++

Comment: SHA is a hash function, not an encryption function. What good is the salt going to do you?

Comment: Hi EJP, Sorry for using the word encryption. salt is adding more security against rainbow table attacks. In openldap they are using salt for sha512 hasing.